# How do I correctly use a custom property added to my Pinia stores in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, pinia

I am using Vue 3 with Pinia; I have an api service that is used to make requests to my api, I've added it as a property to make it available across all my stores, like so:

main.ts:

```ts
import { http } from "@/services/http";

const store = createPinia();
store.use(({ store }) => {
  store.http = http
})
```

Everything seems to work, I can access the api service within my store and use it to fetch data, however typescript complains that the http property does not exist.

stores/system.ts:

```ts
export const useSystemStore = defineStore("system", {
  state: () => ({
    data: <SystemResponse>{
      ...
    }
  }),
  actions: {
    connect() {
      this.http.get("system")  // <-- Property 'http' does not exist on type '{ connect(...
        .then((response) => {
       ...
       ...
```

How can I fix this and make typescript aware of it?

I searched through Pinia's documentation but unfortunately I couldn't find what I needed to solve the issue.

Comment: I propose you something different, just import `http` in your file and use it directly, it's easier, better for tree shaking and help understand dependencies of your store. The only downside is to write `import { http } from "@/services/http"` at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/plugins.html#typing-new-store-properties) says, you need to define your new property on `PiniaCustomProperties` interface.

In your example you should create a file pinia.d.ts and place module declaration there:

```
import 'pinia';

declare module 'pinia' {
  export interface PiniaCustomProperties {
    http: YourHttpTypeGoesHere;
  }
}
```

After that manipulations TS errors should be gone

Comment: That causes TypeScript to stop complaining, but it seems to make TypeScript think that _every_ Pinia store has an `http` property, even if a specific store instance does not have the `http` property. Is there a way to make TypeScript aware that only _certain_ stores have had an `http` property added to them? In other words, I think that `declare module 'pinia'` acts globally; is there a way to accomplish essentially the same thing, but scoped locally to only a specific Pinia store?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Pinia plugins acts globally and adds their functionality to all stores by design. That's why `declare module 'pinia'` is useful here. In situation when you need to share some functionality between only certain stores you can define that stores with [setup syntax](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#setup-stores), store needed functionality in [composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#composables) and reuse it between any amount of stores.

Comment: The problem with this is that if I have a property in my plugin that's optional, then regardless of whether I have set that property, every store still sees the CustomProperties that are defined in the type. 

Using a setup syntax isn't ideal, that means a huge refactor of all the code, and is actually less clean than the options (for our use-case).

Would be really nice if the `PiniaCustomStateProperties` type received the `Store`, then could do conditional on the state.